# Comparison of Grey Matter in regards to "Intelligence"?

Tags: intelligence

Wasn't able to find anything - I'm writing an article about the associations between cortical grey matter and scores on cognitive Intelligence tests.

There are lots of good resources which argue and correlate those two, but I can't find a comparison of an "unintelligent" (performing bad on test) person being examined and an "intelligent" person. Does anyone know a good source?

Comment: Why are the correlations or lack thereof in a population not better than a case study?

Comment: @BryanKrause to re-phrase: I meant a comparison of averagely good and bad test results and their white/grey matter correlation. Whether it’s a case study or multiple persons isn’t the matter - I need two telling MRIs

Comment: Your best bet is probably to look at disease/pathology, like AD. I'd suggest making your question more explicit about what you're looking for, we can't read your mind. "wasn't able to find anything" isn't very helpful.

Comment: @BryanKrause I wasn’t able to find a comparison (MRI) of two brains one of which had a good test result and the other a bad - the MRI focuses on the grey matter proportions

Comment: Unless there is pathology you probably won't see a visible difference. But what I am asking you to explain is why you'd want these pictures rather than the actually informative correlation data.